# have language folders in public, but keep using web.php routes, Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to use tradedoublers. In docs it says I need to put folder in public with the name `de` and in that folder have file for example `123456.html`

When I do that, my nginx gives 403 forbidden when trying to access `website.com/de/` I believe it is looking at public/de when it should look for normal routes in `web.php`

I tried removing it from my public and puttig routes to `web.php`

```
Route::get('/de/123456{extension}', function () {
    return '';
})->where('extension', '(?:.html)?');
```

but it is stil not working with `website.com/de/123456.html` (404 Not Found nginx)  only with `website.com/de/123456.html/`

Comment: Anything in the `public` folder _should_ be accessible without routes. Your 403 might come from `website.com/de/` not having an `index.html` in it. Do you still get a 404 when you remove/disable your routes and access `website.com/de/123456.html`?

Comment: Yes, I can access `website.com/de/123456.html` but issue is when going to `website.com/de/` it gives me 403. Yes, I dont have index.html there, because my localization is handled in web.php. It works with `website.com/de/  website.com/es/ website.com/it/ ` but when I add language folders to public it stops working - 403